# How can put Activity in tabbed activity with view pager

Tags: android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I use tabbed activity with view pager in create menu in android studio and android studio made this for me:

[image]

Now my question is how can put elements like button or another in each of this tabs? Or can make different
 activity for each of these tabs and put them in this view pager?

For example make section1 activity with images and buttons and put that in section 1 tab.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make different types of [**Fragments**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) to achieve this.

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an
>   Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to
>   build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities

following example can help you out.

[**ViewPager Example**](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

You can find out more about **`viewpager`** from here.

[**View Pager**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)